# stripe-react-checkout custom form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, checkout, stripe.js

I've been working on a charity website with React.js and Node.js in which I've used the React-Stripe-Checkout repository to have simple functionality at the very least.

I am now trying to figure out how to customize the form that appears with , or create my own.

Since I've been using this project as a way to really learn how to use React(only did an online bootcamp so far), there's a lot of functionalities and features that I don't yet understand.

I've searched many times online for a way to create a custom integration of Checkout with React but haven't been able to find anything concrete, and I'm not well-versed enough in React to convert the form from another language or framework.

Essentially asking for a tutorial, I would really like to learn how to do this, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? Looks like you can supply your own children. Maybe I'm not understanding the issue here.

Comment: Yes, please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve